psexec query session isn't returning any result when run from jenkins Powershell build step
End Goal : To configure a jenkins job to run a automation script on an windows desktop app in windows active session, am using Jenkins + Psexec command to achieve this goal.
Code that i used is below :
$sessionInfo = & psexec \\$remoteMachine -s -i query session
Write-Output "session info: "+ $sessionInfo

$sessionInfo | Where-Object { $_ -match "^\s*rdp" } | ForEach-Object {
    $fields = $_ -split '\s{2,}'
    if ($fields.Length -ge 4 -and $fields[3] -eq 'Active') {
        $fields[2]
        $sessionId = $fields[2]  # Output the session ID
        Write-Output "inner loop-Session id for current open session : "+ $sessionId
    }
}

psexec \\$remoteMachine -s -i $sessionId powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& {C:\bat-automatic\PS_trail.ps1 -SessID '$sessionId'}"

The above script works completely fine by triggering the automation script in remote machine when i run it from the host powershell app, but when i tried the same with the Jenkins job in the powershell build step, the below command
& psexec \\$remoteMachine -s -i query session

console output of jenkins looks like below :
Connecting to <remoteMahcine1>...
Starting PSEXESVC service on <remoteMahcine1>...
Copying authentication key to <remoteMahcine1>...
Connecting with PsExec service on <remoteMahcine1>...
Starting query on <remoteMahcine1>...

 SESSIONNAME       USERNAME                 ID  STATE   TYPE        DEVICE

query exited on <remoteMahcine1> with error code 1.

so couldn't able to trigger the automation script in an active windows session. In order to achieve this, could anyone point out Where am i making mistake ?

If I had to guess your Jenkins user doesn't have enough permissions. According to the doc:

A user can always query the session to which the user is currently logged on. To query other sessions, the user must have special access permission.

You can try two things:

If querying sessions for the Jenkins user works then it's most likely a permissions issue
Check Security logs for errors around the time when you are making a connection. It might have the information you are looking for


are you referring to Jenkins login user or the user in which Jenkins service log on is configured? The user configured on the Jenkins service is domain administrator account. @iterokun

Yes, I was referring to the Jenkins service user.

I added the user to Administrator group and also the user I used for Jenkins service is a domain administrator who has access too all resources in the machine. But no luck getting the same response.

Here is the doc for permissions.
